# How do you disable the /var/lib/mysql/.err files for Mariadb?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Simple answer desired on how to disable the .err file that grows in /var/lib/mysql.

Server version: 10.0.21-MariaDB MariaDB Server

I followed someone's advice about setting SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF'; but that did not solve the problem.

The problem is specifically /var/lib/mysql/sd-26499.err that is growing constantly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What text is being added to that .err file?  (Maybe you should fix what is causing the error, not sweep it under the rug.)

Answer (score 0):

The error log is active by default and imho it cannot be disabled.

But you can edit your `/etc/my.cnf` and set `log-error=/dev/null` setting the error-log-path to a location, where it's not stored.
This will work, when you are using linux.

You have to restart the mariadb-server after editing the `my.cnf`.

Comment: I get this error : 

Mar 07 02:36:02 sd-26499 mysqld_safe[12427]: touch: cannot touch â/dev/null.errâ: Permission denied
Mar 07 02:36:02 sd-26499 mysqld_safe[12427]: chown: cannot access â/dev/null.errâ: No such file or directory
Mar 07 02:36:02 sd-26499 mysqld_safe[12427]: chmod: cannot access â/dev/null.errâ: No such file or directory
Mar 07 02:36:02 sd-26499 mysqld_safe[12427]: 160307 02:36:02 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
Mar 07 02:36:02 sd-26499 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE